# Linux extended disk

Tags: linux

disks on vmware (/dev/sda) was extended (it is RHEL5, can't use lvm) from 20G to 40G .. if I use fdisk /dev/sda I can create /dev/sda7, but this partition have just 2G, why the partition have just 2G and how I fix it ? thanks

I tried:

```
fdisk /dev/sda and create /dev/sda7

    df -Th
...

/dev/sda2     ext3    6.8G  6.0G  478M  93% /
/dev/sda7     ext3    2.0G   36M  1.9G   2% /home

fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         131     1052226   83  Linux
/dev/sda2             132        1045     7341705   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            1046        1567     4192965   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4            1568        2610     8377897+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1568        2089     4192933+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6            2090        2350     2096451   83  Linux

/dev/sda7            2351        2610     2088418+  83  Linux
```

used also parted:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  1078MB  1077MB  primary   ext3         boot
 2      1078MB  8595MB  7518MB  primary   ext3
 3      8595MB  12.9GB  4294MB  primary   linux-swap
 4      12.9GB  21.5GB  8579MB  extended
 5      12.9GB  17.2GB  4294MB  logical   ext3
 6      17.2GB  19.3GB  2147MB  logical   ext3
        19.3GB  21.5GB  2139MB            Free Space
        21.5GB  42.9GB  21.5GB            Free Space

Warning: You requested a partition from 21.5GB to 42.9GB.
The closest location we can manage is 21.5GB to 21.5GB.  Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No? no
(parted) mkpart
Partition type?  [logical]?
File system type?  [ext2]? ext3
Start? 22G
End? 40G
Warning: You requested a partition from 22.0GB to 40.0GB.
The closest location we can manage is 21.5GB to 21.5GB.  Is this still acceptable to you?
Yes/No? no
(parted)
```

problem is I can't resize more than 2G

Comment: Read about MBR partitioning. You have created 4 primary partitions, you cannot add another primary. fdisk creates another partition inside the extended 4th one. Ex. either repartition it whole or resize the extended partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. type:

   parted /dev/sd?

   (parted) print free
           Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
           32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
    1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary   ext3
    2      1075MB  2149MB  1074MB  primary   ext3
    3      2149MB  3222MB  1074MB  primary   ext3
    4      3222MB  7443MB  4221MB  extended
    5      3223MB  4297MB  1074MB  logical   ext3
    6      4298MB  5372MB  1074MB  logical   ext3
    7      5373MB  5897MB  524MB   logical   ext3
           5897MB  7443MB  1546MB            Free Space
           7443MB  8590MB  1147MB            Free Space

   (parted) resizepart 4
   End?  [7443MB]? 8590MB

   (parted) print free
           Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
           32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
    1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary   ext3
    2      1075MB  2149MB  1074MB  primary   ext3
    3      2149MB  3222MB  1074MB  primary   ext3
    4      3222MB  8590MB  5368MB  extended
    5      3223MB  4297MB  1074MB  logical   ext3
    6      4298MB  5372MB  1074MB  logical   ext3
    7      5373MB  5897MB  524MB   logical   ext3
           5897MB  8590MB  2693MB            Free Space

   (parted) quit

now I resized extended partition